# Compare String Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm studying kotlin, but I'm very disappointed, I can not compare two Strings.

What is the right way to compare.

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener {
            val login = input_email.text.trim()
            val pass = input_password.text.trim()

            if( login.equals( pass ) ){
                startActivity<MainActivity>()
            }

            if (login?.equals(other = pass)){
                startActivity<MainActivity>()
            }

            if (login == pass){
                startActivity<MainActivity>()
            }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: `==` is the right way.

Comment: @Naetmul not works my code... check image

Comment: you can convert to .toString and check with == operator?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala works... tns

Comment: can you check as an answer :)

Comment: Could you explain what were you disappointed in?

Comment: Please don't be disappointed :(

Comment: I've explained it in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772946/equality-in-kotlin/45775038#45775038

Answer (score 50):

According to [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html) for structual equality use `==`. It is translated to `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)`.

In you case convert login and pass from SpannableStringBuilder to String.

```
    val login = input_email.text.trim().toString()
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is the example for matching the two strings using kotlin.

If you are using == (double equals) for matching the string then it's compare the address & return maximum time wrong result as per java documentation so use  **equals**  for the same

If you want to use **equal ignore case** then pass the **true** in the equals method of String

```
if (s1.equals(s2,true))
```

other wise you can just use this without boolean like

```
if (s1.equals(s2,false)) or if (s1.equals(s2))
```

compleate code is below

```
 fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 val s1 = "abc"
 val s2 = "Abc"
 if (s1.equals(s2,true))
 {
    println("Equal")
 }
 else
 {
    println("Not Equal")
 }
}
```

Comment: why "try" ?? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. Please add some description to make others understand. :)

Comment: I have updated the answered with some explanation & thanks for the appreciate me. :)

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Using `==` operator to compare strings is translated to `.equals()` call automatically as the operator is checking *structural equality* (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html#structural-equality)

Answer (score 9):

Covert both the `SpannableStringBuilder` to `string` with `toString`, this should work.

```
val login = input_email.text.trim().toString()
val pass = input_password.text.trim().toString()
if (login == pass){
    startActivity<MainActivity>()
}
```

Answer (score 5):

***1. `==` :***

`if ( string1 == string2 ){...}`

***2. `equals` :***

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
>   Implementations must fulfil the following requirements:
>   Reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should
>   return true.
>
> Symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y)
>   should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
>
> Transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if
>   x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then
>   x.equals(z) should return true
>
> Consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple
>   invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or consistently
>   return false, provided no information used in equals comparisons on
>   the objects is modified.

```
/**  * Returns `true` if this string is equal to [other], optionally ignoring character case.  *  * @param ignoreCase `true` to ignore character case when comparing strings. By default `false`.  */ 
public fun String?.equals(other: String?, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean
```

***3. `compareTo` :***

`public override fun compareTo(other: String): Int`

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns zero
>   if this object is equal to the specified other object, a negative
>   number if it's less than other, or a positive number if it's greater
>   than other.

```
public fun String.compareTo(other: String, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Int
```

> Compares two strings lexicographically, optionally ignoring case
>   differences

Answer (score 5):

i know this is way too late, but as a newbie learning Kotlin, i had the same doubts.

then i came across this [wonderful article](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/compare-strings) that articulates the various string comparison types in Kotlin and the differences between them all.

in short both == and .equals() can be used to compare the value of 2 strings in kotlin.

hopefully that helps

Answer (score 4):

With case checking

```
String a=.....
String b=.....
if(a==b){
}
```

IgnoreCase

```
if(a.equals(b,false))
```

Answer (score 1):

**KOTLIN:**

```
if (editText1.text.toString() == editText2.text.toString() ) {
   println("Should work now! The same value")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution, see if it helps:

```
val passStr: String = textView.text.toString()  
if( loginStr.compareTo(passStr, false) ){
            startActivity<MainActivity>()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this surely will work.

```
val style = buildString { karthik}
val style2 = buildString { karthik }
var result = style.equals(style2)
if(result){//Do something}
```