# Equality in Kotlin

Tags: java, operator-overloading, kotlin, operators, equality

I'm learning Kotlin, with a C++ and Java background. I was expecting the following to print `true`, not `false`. I know that `==` maps to `equals`. Does the default implementation of `equals` not compare each member, i.e. `firstName` and `lastName`? If so, wouldn't it see the string values as equal (since `==` maps to `equals` again)? Apparently there's something related to equality versus identity that I haven't got right in Kotlin yet.

```
class MyPerson(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   println(MyPerson("Charlie", "Parker") == MyPerson("Charlie", "Parker"))
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The default `equals` implementation you're describing exists only for data classes. Not for regular classes where the implementation is inherited from `Any`, and just make the object equal to itself.

Comment: So, if equals is not overridden for a regular class, it's essentially the same as calling ===.

Comment: @stdout Exactly the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 61):

#### Referential Equality

**Java**

In Java, the default implementation of `equals` compares the variable's [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), which is what `==` **always** does:

> The `equals` method for class `Object` implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns `true` **if and only if x**
>   **and y refer to the same object** (`x == y` has the value `true`).

We call this "**referential** equality".

**Kotlin**

In Kotlin `==` is compiled to `equals`, whereas `===` is the equivalent of Java's `==`.

#### Structural Equality

Whenever we want rather *structural* than *referential* equality, we can override `equals`, which is *never* done by default for *normal* classes, as you suggested. In Kotlin, we can use `data class`, for which the compiler automatically creates an implementation based on the constructor properties (read [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)).

Please remember to always override `hashCode` if you override `equals` (and vice versa) **manually** and stick to the very strict [contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java) of both methods. Kotlin's compiler-generated implementations do satisfy the contract.

Comment: In kotlin you can **ctrl + click** the `==` operator and you will see that is the same as  `equals` as this answer tells, if you **ctrl + click** on the `equals` method you will also see that links to the same implementation.

Answer (score 17):

> **== for equality**
>
> In Java, you can use == to compare primitive and reference types. If applied to primitive types, Java’s == compares values, whereas == on reference types compares references. Thus, in Java, there’s the well-known practice of always calling equals, and there’s the well-known problem of forgetting to do so.
>
> In Kotlin, == is the default way to compare two objects: it compares their values by calling equals under the hood. Thus, if equals is overridden in your class, you can safely compare its instances using ==. For reference comparison, you can use the === operator, which works exactly the same as == in Java.

```
class MyPerson(val firstName: String, val lastName: String){
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other == null || other !is MyPerson) return false
        return firstName == other.firstName && lastName == other.lastName
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(MyPerson("Charlie", "Parker") == MyPerson("Charlie", "Parker")) // print "true"
}
```

In your case `MyPerson` is used to be a `data class` which autogenerate implementations of universal methods (`toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode`).