# why kotlin use === compare primitive type equal each other if they has same value

Tags: kotlin

```
val hello1 = "hello"
val hello2 = "hello"
printf(hello1 === hello2)
```

why print true?

I guess kotlin has a primitive type pool(or something like that).
If the value is equality,a pointer points to same place.I'm not sure.

Comment: Note that `String` is not a primitive type.

Comment: even so why get true, i thought only primitive type

Comment: Because `===` compares references, and just like in Java, there is a string pool - string literals are shared in the pool, so if you have two string literals with the same content then there is only one `String` object and both your variables point to the same object.

Comment: I mean val a1 =1   
 val a2=1  
print(a1 === a2)
get ture, why? there is a Integer pool?

Comment: No. In that example `a1` and `a2` are not `Integer` objects, they are just primitive values - not objects. `===` just compares the values. Exactly the same as what `==` does in Java.

Comment: if write val a1:Int =1    val a2:Int =2 , they are still primitive values?
How to judge a object or primitive

Comment: There is a [fixed set of primitive types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html): Double, Float, Long, Int, Short, Byte, Char, Boolean. Those are primitive types, any other type is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Equality in Kotlin

I explained the general equality tools used in Kotlin in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45775038/8073652). 
TLDR:

1. structural equality: `==` is compiled to Java's `equals`
2. Referential equality: `===` is what `==` does in Java: References are compared to each other. It yields `true` if *the same* objects are being compared.

#### What about Strings like in your example?

Strings are special in that they work with a so called *string constant pool*. For example, even in Java, the following is `true` for both comparisons:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "prasad";
    String s2 = "prasad";

    System.out.println(s.equals(s2));
    System.out.println(s == s2);
}
```

On the other hand, the next snippet does work differently since `new` Strings are being created:

```
String foo = new String("hello");
String bar = new String("hello");
System.out.println(foo == bar);  // prints 'false'
```

Read about it here: [What is the Java string pool and how is "s" different from new String("s")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings)

FYI: `String`s are not primitive.

Comment: No this particular feature is dedicated to `String`

Comment: Even so why other primitive types run === will also get true

Comment: For primitives it is like you say, but string isn’t a primitive, strings are objects which makes it special (the pool)

Answer (score 6):

> [a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Kotlin simply reuses the same mechanism. See [Is String Literal Pool a collection of references to the String Object, Or a collection of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700320/is-string-literal-pool-a-collection-of-references-to-the-string-object-or-a-col) and [Java String literal pool and string object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046045/java-string-literal-pool-and-string-object) for additional explanations.

Comment: Kotlin has no primitive type?
I only saw Int,Boolean,Double... <- class

Comment: Just because it looks like a class doesn't mean it has to be represented as a class in bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

> In Kotlin there are two types of equality:
>
> - Referential equality (two references point to the same object);
> - Structural equality (a check for equals()).
>
> **Referential equality** is checked by the `===` operation (and its negated counterpart `!==`). `a === b` evaluates to true if and only if
>   a and b point to the **same object**.
>
> **Structural equality** is checked by the `==` operation (and its negated counterpart `!=`). By convention, an expression like `a == b`
>   is translated to:So you see

```
a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)
```

So you see: `==` means `equals` and `===` means referential equality

That would imply that

```
val hello1 = "hello"
val hello2 = "hello"
printf(hello1 === hello2)
```

is referential compared which should lead to `false`.
BUT: When you use a string literal like `"hello"`, the string cache of java is used (this is an optimization to save memory). So you get both times the same reference, and therefore the reference equality is true.

Comment: Kotlin has no primitive type? I only saw Int,Boolean,Double... <- class

Comment: Kotlin do have primitives, but the compiler decides when to use it and when to use the wrapper types. so `Int`, `Boolean`, ... will be compiled to primitive types in the bytecode in most situations (when they are not involved in generics or you use the nullable-variant of the type `Int?`)