# kotlin not working when i present letter condition

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to learning kotlin.
I want a make a android app.
But im getting error.

i want to if i write  "A" to edittext(@+id/tehlikesinifi), textview (uzmanucret) give me "40"
i write  "B" to edittext(@+id/tehlikesinifi), textview (uzmanucret) give me "20"
i write  "C" to edittext(@+id/tehlikesinifi), textview (uzmanucret)give me "10"

```
import abdullah.aydin.aykanosgb.databinding.ActivityFiyat2Binding
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle



class fiyat2 : AppCompatActivity() {
   private lateinit var binding: ActivityFiyat2Binding
   @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       binding=ActivityFiyat2Binding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(binding.root)
       var cs= binding.calisansayisi.text.toString()
       var usaat=binding.usaatucret.text.toString()

       var ts=binding.tehlikesinifi.text.toString()
       var uzmanucret  =binding.uzmanucret.text.toString()

       binding.button.setOnClickListener {

           if (ts.equals( "A")){
               var uzmandk =40

           }else if(ts.equals("B")){
               var uzmandk  =20

           }else if(ts.equals("C")){
               var uzmandk =10
           }
           var uzmandk: String=""
           var sonuc: String
           sonuc= uzmandk
           var sonuc1 = sonuc
           binding.uzmanucret.text= "$sonuc"


       }


   }

}
```

Comment: `var uzmandk =40` , `var uzmandk  =20` you are creating a new variable everywhere, declare it once and change the value of it, don't add `var` or you'll make a new variable

Comment: When you say you are getting error, please include the error message in your post.

Comment: sorry its not error message. İn app when i write; textview dont work.

Comment: i try only ; var uzmandk =40 . its not work.

Answer (score 0):

- You have many redundant variables which make your code messy
- `ts` is set only once in `onCreate` and never get updated. To get the latest value you typed in the `EditText`, you should get it within the `onClickListener`
- [Kotlin control flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html) expression can return a value. It is more suitable to use `when` in your case
- You don't need to call `equals` to [compare string in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44876707/compare-string-kotlin).

---

```
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        binding.uzmanucret.text = when(binding.tehlikesinifi.text.toString()){
            "A" -> "40"
            "B" -> "20"
            "C" -> "10"
            else -> null
        }
    }
```